# phpMyAdmin on Linux takes too long to load

Tags: phpmyadmin, database

Why does it take too long to load the database that I had just created? Other actions like executing a sql statement works.  Btw, I'm running a Linux OS in my flash drive. Does this happen because I'm running it on a flash drive?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an older flash drive with much slower writes than reads (which many had once upon a time), I could see this behavior happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed phpmyadmin trough apt-get, eg `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`, than it might be worthwhile to [download the newest version of phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/). Just download the zip/tar file and extract it in /var/www/html.